# What is the Minecraft scoreboard command to display words?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a server and I want it to be able to show ranks on the sidebar (VIP, Diamond, ect.). I have tried to use the scoreboard command with a dummy but it does not accept words. Is there a way I can display ranks on the sidebar without mods or plugins?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't display words?  In my experience I have no problem displaying words.

Comment: when i try to use /scoreboard players add Padraig_P rank VIP it says VIP not valid number.

Comment: i might need to try set...

Comment: nope doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the type of value shown on the sidebar in vanilla; it will always be a name followed by an integer score.

However, you can use vanilla's team prefix/suffix feature to display text before or after the names of those within the team (which includes fake players/non-player entities).

### In-game

Create scoreboard teams to represent ranks.

```
/scoreboard teams add VIP
/scoreboard teams add Diamond
```

Insert players into the appropriate teams.

```
/scoreboard teams join VIP @p
```

Create a dummy objective to show on the sidebar and initialize players with a score of 0. The score itself won't matter unless you want to sort players in a specific manner.

```
/scoreboard objectives add Display dummy
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Display
/scoreboard players set @a Display 0
```

---

However, if you wanted to order it based on rank, you can give players with a higher rank a higher score:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[team=VIP] Display 2
/scoreboard players set @a[team=Diamond] Display 1
```

### Editing team prefix/suffix

Exit the world. Navigate to the `<world name>/data/scoreboard.dat` file and open it with an NBT editor such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac).

Open the `data` compound, the `Teams` list, and then locate the teams you want to modify. Edit the prefix/suffix to include text for display, which can include section-symbol-formatted codes.

[image: scoreboard.dat > data > Teams > (a team) > Suffix]

### Final result

When you enter the world again, your name will include the additional text:

[image: Skylinerw(VIP): 0]

Comment: thanks but its a realms server

Comment: @hyperviper11: Apparently, you're able to download the world, make the edit, and then re-upload it.  I don't use Realms, so I can't really tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Run Once:

```
/team add VIP
/team modify prefix {"text":"[VIP]: ","color":"green"}

/scoreboard objectives add Sidebar dummy {"text":"Side Bar","color":"blue"}
```

Loop:

```
/team join VIP @p[tag=VIP]
```

Chain:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[tag=VIP] Sidebar 0
```